# Output terms to post_class()

Tags: css, terms, post-class

I am trying to output all terms attached to a specific post (including custom taxonomy terms) as CSS classes applied to a DIV
Something like that :

```
   <div <?php post_class('class-name'); ?>></div>
```

So it outputs something like this :

```
  <div class="class-name term1 term2 term3 term4"></div>
```

How do I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: sorry, I probably wasn't clear enough. I need it to output terms from my custom taxonomy, which it doesn't right now.

Comment: What additional terms do you want? I know you want classes that have to do with a custom taxonomy but what exactly? The taxonomy name? All the terms for the taxonomy?

Comment: yes, I want the terms attached from a certain taxonomy or terms from multiple taxonomies.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most straight-forward way to do this would be:

```
$tax_terms = get_the_terms(
  $post->ID,
  array('genre')
);
$tax_terms = wp_list_pluck($tax_terms,'slug');
post_class(implode(' ',$tax_terms));
```

You could also apply a filter to `post_class` that does essentially the same.

```
function tax_classes_wpse_105386($classes) {
  global $post;
  $tax_terms = get_the_terms(
$post->ID,
array('genre')
  );
  $tax_terms = wp_list_pluck($tax_terms,'slug');
  $classes = array_merge($classes,$tax_terms);
  return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class','tax_classes_wpse_105386');
```

I am sure you want more complicated logic though-- for example, restrict this only to certain post types perhaps.

Comment: I think you want `get_the_terms`, not `get_terms`.

Comment: @milo : yes probably. That is what I get for posting while being rushed out the door.

Comment: Right, don't forget there's also `the_terms`. Now only `the_get_terms` is missing. Sometimes I wonder why I'm still using this ridiculous piece of software, or worse- help others use it...